# Jquery not working while browsing with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Hello I'm using this code:

```
$("#cart").click(function () {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.content').length > 0) return false;
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
    var e = window.event || e;
    $("#cart").toggleClass("active");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $("#cart").removeClass("active");
        $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function () {
            // Code Here
        });
    });
});
```

It works just fine in Chrome but when testing it in Firefox it doesn't work. The line that doesn't work is:

```
if ($(event.target).closest('.content').length>0) return false;
```

Why does this work in Chrome but not in Firefox ?

Comment: Does it gives any error in firefox console

Comment: It gives me "ReferenceError: event is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pass event argument

try like this

```
$("#cart").click(function(event) {
  // now put your code here
}
```

Comment: Oh, that was a pretty simple fix ! I feel pretty stupid now, I guess I overlooked it haha. May I ask why does it work in Chrome though ?

Comment: There is `window.event` which handle event but for firefox he don't support it. even in strict mode also don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `event` as an argument for your listener.

```
$("#cart").click(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.content').length > 0) return false;
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
    var e = window.event || e;
    $("#cart").toggleClass("active");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $("#cart").removeClass("active");
        $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function () {
            // Code Here
        });
    });
});
```